# Swift: self reference in nested closures

Tags: swift, cocoa, key-value-observing, completionhandler

I am using the new block based KVO API in Swift to observe properties. 
Below is the sample code.

```
class A: NSObject {
var observerA: NSKeyValueObservation? = nil
var observerB: NSKeyValueObservation? = nil

var property1: CustomObj1?
var property2: CustomObj2?

func doSomething() {

}

func doSomethingElse() {

}

func observeValues() {
    observerA = customObj1.observe(\.property1, options: [], changeHandler: { [weak self] (obj, change) in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.doSomething()
        strongSelf.observerB = customObj2.observe(\.property2, options: [], changeHandler: { [weak strongSelf] (nestedObj, nestedChange) in
            guard let nestedStrongSelf = strongSelf else { return }
            nestedStrongSelf.doSomethingElse()
        })
    })
}
```

}

My question is how do we refer to `self` in the inner change handler block. 
I could use it as it above and I don't see any memory leaks.   But using `self` in place of `strongSelf` in "[weak strongSelf]" within inner change handler also does not cause any issues. Here is the code.

```
func observeValues() {
observerA = self.observe(\.property1, options: [], changeHandler: { [weak self] (obj, change) in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.doSomething()
    strongSelf.observerB = strongSelf.observe(\.property2, options: [], changeHandler: { [weak self] (nestedObj, nestedChange) in
        guard let nestedStrongSelf = self else { return }
        nestedStrongSelf.doSomethingElse()
    })
})
```

}

My question is how should `self` be referred within nested completion handlers and what should be the best practice in this. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize for my wrong answer earlier! It turns out that you're absolutely right. I always use `[unowned self]` to handle this situation.

Comment: Why don't you use `[weak self]` as you have found it causes no problem?

Comment: Yep that can be done. But I just ended up using `strongSelf` for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see any memory leaks, even if you had a strong reference cycle, until all other strong references disappear.

For example, if this VC is alive for the whole app lifetime, even if a closure was capturing a strong reference cycle, it wouldn't do anything. The impact would be the same: the VC would be alive for the whole app lifetime, which it was already doing anyway.

You would be able to identify a memory leak only if you had a strong reference cycle, and then tried deinitializing the VC by deleting all other strong refs.

Comment: The VC will not be alive for the lifetime of the app and I would want the VC and its model controller to be deallocated once the screen the VC represents is closed.  I am not having any retain issues with the above code. I am looking for the best way to access self in a nested change handler. Should I just refer self as 'self' in the nested block or I should refer to the weaker version of the self(strongSelf) declared in the  capture list of the parent block.

Comment: @SwiftTechnocrat So when you close that VC's screen, you should see a memory leak in Instruments.

Comment: Yes I do see a memory leak and deinit is never executed when I dont declare self as weak in the parent block.

Comment: @SwiftTechnocrat Yep, that makes sense. I don't think I understand your question then, what are you asking? In the nest scoped, you have to capture `self` weakly, just the same.

Comment: Yep the self should be captured weakly. Doesn't matter if it is referred as `self` or the weak version of `self` i.e. `strongSelf` in this case. Technically both are the same. I was under the impression that using `self` as it is in the nested block, for capture list, might cause retain cycles. Thanks for your inputs.